# Why does bootstrap grid placed my right aligned li into next row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have the following markup which basically is suppose to have the Website Name on the left and 2 list items aligned to the right of the navbar.   This works but as I reduce the size of the browser so that it gets to the x-small break point, the 2 list items then jumps and appears on 2 rows left aligned.  Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:hotpink">WebsiteName</div>
            <div class="col-xs-10" style="background-color:aquamarine">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>menu 1</li>
                    <li>menu 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to overwrite the bootstrap media queries layout for li.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the media queries for Bootstrap's col-xs to force a breaking point at an even further point. The less properties can be found here:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

You could use that to recompile bootstrap and upload it to your project again with the new breaking point for col-xs. It should be straightforward enough from there. I strongly recommend this option because those changes should be done in LESS.

And if you want this change only for this specific instance then try using min-width on your divs but I don't think that this will hold for all browsers at all points.